# scala DSLs and typed operators: idiomatic implementation?

Tags: scala, operators, dsl

Consider:

```
val a:ExpressionT[Int] = Const(1)
val b:ExpressionT[Float] = Const(2.0f)

// + must raise types:
//    (i+i) -> i
//    (i+f) -> f
//    (f+i) -> f
//    (f+f) -> f
val c:ExpressionT[Float] = a+b
```

where:

```
// A typed Expression
trait ExpressionT[T] extends Expression{
   def evaluate(): T
}

class Const[T<:Any](value:T) extends ExpressionT[T]  {
   def evaluate(): T = value
}

object Const {
  def apply(value:Int) = new Const[Int](value) 
  def apply(value:Float) = new Const[Float](value)
}
```

What's the most elegant way to implement the + operator that will work for all numeric types? Is there a way to avoid enumerating all combinations of types?

In C++ this we can simply (from memory):

```
template <typename T>
class ExpressionT {
    typedef typename T EvalT; 
    virtual T evaluate() const = 0;
}

// HighestType<X,Y>::EvalT,       
// (int,float) --> float
// (float,int) --> float
// (int,int) --> int
template <typename X, typename Y>
class Add : public ExpressionT<  HighestType<X::EvalT, Y::EvalT>::EvalT > {

    Add(Expression<X> const& l, Expression<X> const& r) {...}
    inline ResultT evaluate() { return l+r; }
}

template <typename X, typename Y>
auto operator + ( Expression<T> const& lhs, 
                  Expression<T> const& rhs ){
    return Add(lhs, rhs);
}
```

... which requires no per-type cases, will also happily fail to compile if  +(lhs,rhs) is not defined, and also straightforwardly permits extension to new unseen types  +(int, Matrix), +(Matrix, float), without any additional work.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
  implicit class ExpressionCalc[T](val it: ExpressionT[T])(implicit numeric: Numeric[T]) {
    def +(that: ExpressionT[T]) =
      new Const(numeric.plus(it.evaluate(), that.evaluate()))
  }  

 println(Const(5) + Const(6))
 println(Const(5.6f) + Const(6))
```

Unfortunately it does not fully cover what you would want to do. In your case you want to return `Float` whenever at least one of the arguments is `Float`.

But you can try https://github.com/saddle/saddle/, it allows you to do what you want:

```
 object Const {
    def apply(value:Int) = new Const[Int](value)
    def apply(value:Double) = new Const[Double](value)
  }

  implicit class ExpressionCalc[This](val it: ExpressionT[This]) {
    def +[That, R](that: ExpressionT[That])(implicit op: BinOp[Add, This, That, R]): ExpressionT[R] = {
      new Const(op(it.evaluate(), that.evaluate()))
    }
  }

  println(Const(5) + Const(6))
  println(Const(5.6) + Const(6))
  println(Const(5) + Const(6.7))
```

Note that saddle does not support `Float`, so I've changed it to `Double`. You could also try to look how saddle implemented it's `BinOp`, and use the same approach in your code